# Add AVI to Blender Animation

Tags: node-editor

I have an AVI file rendered from an animation. I would like to play it on a "TV" in a different animation. I have added it as an image texture on the "TV" and if I step through the frames I see the animation. But when I run the animation (Alt+A) there is no animation on the "TV", only the first frame. If I stop the run (Alt+A again) the "TV" shows the correct AVI frame.  I haven't tried a full-up render of the new animation because each frame takes about 8 min.
The question: how can I get the AVI "movie" to play on the "TV" in my "living room" scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @DuarteFarrajotaRamos said in comments (and his answer to the linked question) it's a current limit in viewport implementation, and it should work when rendered.

While the animation, though the video will not be updated in the 3d viewport, you can click on the viewport (anywhere) to see the "current" frame. Not so useful, but it shows at least what is shown at that frame...

But there's a (silly) temporary workaround if you need to see that video really playing in the viewport: start playing the animation with the shortcut (<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) **while hovering the mouse cursor** in the right-side texture preview panel, like shown here (note: my screen capturing tool doesn't show the cursor, just the clicks):

[image]

so, if you need to see something, at least you have some way to go...